# PHP - mysqli_query - WHERE and date

Tags: php, date

I have a PHP query that I only want to select if the date is 2014 in the table:

```
$result=mysqli_query($linkID, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date(Y) = '2014'";
```

I'm trying to call "date(Y)" with the correct expression as that is obviously incorrect.

Comment: "date(Y)" is the part I am trying to substitute for the right expression, calling for only rows that have a date of 2014.

Comment: so what is `Y` in particular? "only rows that have a date of 2014" --- rows have a date of 2014 *where*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$result=mysqli_query($linkID, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(datetime_field) = 2014");
```

Answer (score 1):

the query should be

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(the_date_field) = 2014
```

`the_date_field` is the field containing the date of course